# Get the latest file addition in a directory

Tags: php

How to get the latest file name, or the file path that is added into a directory?

Comment: filectime is for when metadata like chmod values are changed.
filemtime is for actual content change.

Comment: To clear up any confusion: The [`c` in `filectime()` does not stand for `creation`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) and the [`C` in `getCTime()` does not stand for `creation`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getctime.php)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
$path = "/path/to/my/dir"; 

$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    

$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
  // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
    $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
    $latest_filename = $entry;
  }
}

// now $latest_filename contains the filename of the file that changed last
```

Comment: [ctime is not creation time](http://userprimary.net/posts/2007/11/18/ctime-in-unix-means-last-change-time-not-create-time/)

Comment: any new method for fastest searching or scan?

Comment: @Muhaimin Abdul  Try scandir() ~ PHP 5

Comment: As others have mentioned in other answers...   should probably be using `filemtime` instead of `filectime`.    a) it's more widely supported across platforms.   b) It returns what you're probably wanting: the time that the file was last modified

Answer (score 6):

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$lastMod = 0;
$lastModFile = '';
foreach (scandir($dir) as $entry) {
    if (is_file($dir.$entry) && filectime($dir.$entry) > $lastMod) {
        $lastMod = filectime($dir.$entry);
        $lastModFile = $entry;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$dir = "/path/to/Your/dir";         
$pattern = '\.(zip|ZIP|pdf|PDF)$'; // check only file with these ext.          
$newstamp = 0;            
$newname = "";

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {               
       while (false !== ($fname = readdir($handle)))  {            
         // Eliminate current directory, parent directory            
         if (ereg('^\.{1,2}$',$fname)) continue;            
         // Eliminate other pages not in pattern            
         if (! ereg($pattern,$fname)) continue;            
         $timedat = filemtime("$dir/$fname");            
         if ($timedat > $newstamp) {
            $newstamp = $timedat;
            $newname = $fname;
          }
         }
        }
closedir ($handle);

// $newstamp is the time for the latest file
// $newname is the name of the latest file
// print last mod.file - format date as you like            
print $newname . " - " . date( "Y/m/d", $newstamp);
```

Comment: This uses a depreciated function: ereg()

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do it using [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php):

```
foreach(new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/read') as $item) {
    if ($item->isFile() && (empty($file) || $item->getMTime() > $file->getMTime())) {
        $file = clone $item;
    }
}
```

The resulting contents of `$file` is an instance of the DirectoryIterator class and as such you have access to all of it's methods.  To simply get the full path of the result you can do:

```
echo $file->getPathname();
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution with PHP 5:

```
$dir = "/path/to/Your/dir"; 
$arraydir =scandir($dir, 1);
echo "arraydir 0: " . $arraydir[0] . "<br/>"; // 1. new file
echo "arraydir 1: " . $arraydir[1] . "<br/>"; // 2. new file
echo "arraydir elements: " . count($arraydir) . "<br/>";
```

(search words DE: neuste und zweitneuste Datei eines Ordners anzeigen mit PHP )

Comment: This sorts by name, will work only if you have alphabetically sortable timestamps in the filename, like `exported_data_20170721.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate all directory files, get the filemtime() of each and you are done.

Comment: I think you rather need `filectime`.

Comment: @Gumbo: why use filectime instead of filemtime. I see filemtime() work better on a multitude of platforms while filectime() does not seem to work properly on all Windows servers.

Comment: @secretlm `filectime` probably doesn't work because its only the creation time of the file, not the modification time