# PHP: How to get the latest created FOLDER in a given directory

Tags: php, directory

I have seen many tackling the problem of getting the latest created FILES in a given directory [PHP: Get the Latest File Addition in a Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491020/php-get-the-latest-file-addition-in-a-directory) and [How to get the newest file in a directory in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597421/how-to-get-the-newest-file-in-a-directory-in-php); however, how can I get the name of the  newly created FOLDER in this directory using PHP?

Comment: In the first example you linked, function used is `is_file`. There's a function called `is_dir`. You should be able to figure it out on your own using these hints.

Comment: I'm glad you got it on your own! :)