# Get name of the last modified file in directory

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I have a directory with backups. Those files have the name like this: `date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').".sql` . When I want to restore the files I need the last modified file to backup. How do I get the name of that file to use it in code?

This is the code for restore:

```
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < '.$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command);
```

What do I have to write on `$mysqlImportFilename`?

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597421/how-to-get-the-newest-file-in-a-directory-in-php

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491020/get-the-latest-file-addition-in-a-directory

Comment: trying, I will reply if it works

Comment: I get the last file as $lastfile but when I put this in $command is not working. Why?