# Auto Numbering File on Upload

Tags: php, upload, thumbnails, jpeg, file-rename

I have edited the title, so I hope this one will be helpful...

Case:
I have many images and have uploaded it to a server. I was manually change their names with numbers. Of course I remember the last number of the file but could anyone help me with upload script that enable me to check the last number existed on the server folder and rename the file I'm gonna upload so that the name of the file is last_number_exist_on_server+1?

Ah, helping on generating the thumbnail to a specific folder and size will be appreciated also.

Last but not least, I am using PHP. No database... and the image file type is JPG.

Sorry, newbie's question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491020/php-get-the-latest-file-addition-in-a-directory just as a tip - read the filename add ++ and there you go ;)

Answer (score 2):

Note: there is zero error checking here.  Add some before you use in production! :)

```
<?php

// get the next number for our filename

// returns an array of files and directories in descending alpha-order
$files = scandir("./images", SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);

$last_filename = array_shift($files);
$last_number   = (int)substr($last_filename, 0, strrpos($last_filename, "."));
$next_number   = $last_number++;

// now rename your file...
?>
```