# How to load image which of last upload?

Tags: php

I am loading a image which is **jpg** but what if the user uploads a **png** file or **jpeg** file as profile image where he already had a file in **jpg**.

SAME NAME example : abc@mail.com_profileimage.ext

I am getting this image by direct link through url.

```
<img style="width: 100%" src="http://proconstruct.co.in/upload_images/<?php echo $email.'_profileimage.jpg';?>" onerror="this.src = 'http://proconstruct.co.in/images/noimage.jpg'; ">
```

If i use `$images = glob($dirname . "*");`    with the give prefix above how can i get last saved image

UPLOAD and CROP CODE

```
<?php

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$upload_path = "upload_images/";

$thumb_width = "150";
$thumb_height = "150";


function resizeThumbnailImage($thumb_image_name, $image, $width, $height, $start_width, $start_height, $scale){
    list($imagewidth, $imageheight, $imageType) = getimagesize($image);
    $imageType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);

    $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
    $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
    switch($imageType) {
        case "image/gif":
            $source=imagecreatefromgif($image);
            break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":
            $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
            break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":
            $source=imagecreatefrompng($image);
            break;
    }
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$start_width,$start_height,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
    switch($imageType) {
        case "image/gif":
            imagegif($newImage,$thumb_image_name);
            break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":
            imagejpeg($newImage,$thumb_image_name,100);
            break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":
            imagepng($newImage,$thumb_image_name);
            break;
    }
    chmod($thumb_image_name, 0777);
    return $thumb_image_name;
}



if (isset($_POST["upload_thumbnail"])) {

    $filenam = $_POST['filename'];
        $filenam = pathinfo($filenam);
        $extn = $filenam['extension'];

    $large_image_location = $upload_path.$_POST['filename'];
    $thumb_image_location = $upload_path."thumb_".$_POST['filename'];
        $myemail = $this->session->userdata('email');
      $thumb_image_location = $upload_path.$myemail."_profileimage.".$extn;

    $x1 = $_POST["x1"];
    $y1 = $_POST["y1"];
    $x2 = $_POST["x2"];
    $y2 = $_POST["y2"];
    $w = $_POST["w"];
    $h = $_POST["h"];

    $scale = $thumb_width/$w;
    $cropped = resizeThumbnailImage($thumb_image_location, $large_image_location,$w,$h,$x1,$y1,$scale);
    header("location:".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    exit();
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Upload File and Crop</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cropimage.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/imgareaselect-default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.imgareaselect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submitbtn').click(function() {
            $("#viewimage").html('');
            $("#viewimage").html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
            $(".uploadform").ajaxForm({
                url: 'upload_sup',
                success:    showResponse
            }).submit();
        });
    });

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){

        if(responseText.indexOf('.')>0){
            $('#thumbviewimage').html('<img src="<?php echo $upload_path; ?>'+responseText+'"   style="position: relative;" alt="Thumbnail Preview" />');
            $('#viewimage').html('<img class="preview" alt="" src="<?php echo $upload_path; ?>'+responseText+'"   id="thumbnail" />');
            $('#filename').val(responseText);
            $('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({  aspectRatio: '1:1', handles: true  , onSelectChange: preview });
        }else{
            $('#thumbviewimage').html(responseText);
            $('#viewimage').html(responseText);
        }
    }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function preview(img, selection) {
    var scaleX = <?php echo $thumb_width;?> / selection.width;
    var scaleY = <?php echo $thumb_height;?> / selection.height;

    $('#thumbviewimage > img').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * img.width) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(scaleY * img.height) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
    });

    var x1 = Math.round((img.naturalWidth/img.width)*selection.x1);
    var y1 = Math.round((img.naturalHeight/img.height)*selection.y1);
    var x2 = Math.round(x1+selection.width);
    var y2 = Math.round(y1+selection.height);

    $('#x1').val(x1);
    $('#y1').val(y1);
    $('#x2').val(x2);
    $('#y2').val(y2);

    $('#w').val(Math.round((img.naturalWidth/img.width)*selection.width));
    $('#h').val(Math.round((img.naturalHeight/img.height)*selection.height));

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save_thumb').click(function() {
        var x1 = $('#x1').val();
        var y1 = $('#y1').val();
        var x2 = $('#x2').val();
        var y2 = $('#y2').val();
        var w = $('#w').val();
        var h = $('#h').val();
        if(x1=="" || y1=="" || x2=="" || y2=="" || w=="" || h==""){
            alert("Please Make a Selection First");
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    });
});
</script>



</head>
<body style="background-color: #6db4e7">

<!-- content -->
<section>
<div class="container">

    <div class="crop_box">
<form class="uploadform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='upload.php' name="photo">
    <div class="crop_set_upload">
        <div class="crop_upload_label">Upload files: </div>
        <div class="crop_select_image"><div class="file_browser"><input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile" class="hide_broswe" /></div></div>
        <div class="crop_select_image"><input type="submit" value="Upload" class="upload_button" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
        <div class="crop_set_preview">
            <div class="crop_preview_left">
                <div class="crop_preview_box_big" id='viewimage'>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="crop_preview_right">
                Preview Image
                <div class="crop_preview_box_small" id='thumbviewimage' style="position:relative; overflow:hidden;"> </div>

                <form name="thumbnail" action="profileimage" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="" id="x1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="" id="y1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="" id="x2" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="" id="y2" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" id="w" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" id="h" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="wr" value="" id="wr" />

                    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="" id="filename" />
                    <div class="crop_preview_submit"><input type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save Thumbnail" id="save_thumb" class="submit_button" /> </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to call recursive function pls have look on this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491020/php-get-the-latest-file-addition-in-a-directory

Comment: I understood your requirement,can you please post your code also.

Comment: Lalit Sharma : ctime is not creation time its changed time i need creation time

Comment: USER : there is the code i have updated in question